# Link vertical alignment, height 100%

Tags: html, css, hyperlink, alignment, vertical-alignment

How can I vertical center the text 'Test' in the right red box on http://beta.ovoweb.net/a.php# ?
The link has a height of 100%, so it fills the whole td. Now when I set display: table-cell, the height isn't 100% anymore.

Comment: The vertical-align property should work, but you'll need to either change the height of the A element or try wrapping the text in a span, I guess, https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/vertical-align

Comment: I just thought about it, and padding the contents on the inside might work too.

Answer (score 0):

add this to your "icon" class

```
margin-top: auto
```

and remove

```
height:100%
```

Comment: But then it's not 100% anymore ;).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to go the "display:table-cell" route, I'm pretty sure that you need a parent div that has "display:table;" and "height:100%;" (don't forget to set the parent width also)